# (c++) problem in printing words of char array string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm making a c++ program using string(data type) and char array. Now, the data type is printing words alright. But, I'm having some trouble with the char array. Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char str[200]; 
    string str1;
    cout<<"Enter a string:\t";
    getline(cin,str1);
    cout<<str1 <<endl;
    cout<<"enter second string:\t";
    cin>>str;
    cin.get(str,200);
    cout<<str;

}
```

[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU0Fp.png)

As, you can see in the output, the data type string is printing the words fine. But, the char array is missing the first word. Am I doing something wrong? or does the char array work in different way? Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: "using string(data type) and char array" Why?

Comment: ` cin>>str;
    cin.get(str,200);` You read first word, then you read up to 200 chars to the same variable....

Comment: @Yunnosch because well, i wanted to understand the working of both

Comment: @Kamil thanks man i didnt notice that. thanks

Comment: Why are you including `string.h`? How old is your compiler? Why do you not have `<<endl` after `cout <<str;`? (nobody likes it when you mess up their prompt -- and all POSIX compatible programs should output a final `'\n'` after their final output -- because nobody likes it when you mess up their prompt `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have already discovered that `cin >> str;` isn't required as you are simply writing again to `str` with `cin.getline (str, sizeof str)`, there are a number of additional issues you should address:

**1.** Unless your compiler is ancient, you should `#include <string>`, not the C-header `string.h`;

**2.** Don't use *magic-numbers* in your code. If you need a constant, e.g. for the maximum number of characters in `str`, `#define` a constant or use a global `enum` to do the same, e.g.

```
#define MAXC 200    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
    char str[MAXC]; /* don't use 'magic-number', use a constant */
```

That way when, and if you change the number of characters in `str` in the future, you don't have to pick through your entire code and change every occurrence of the *magic-number*, e.g. `cin.get(str,200);`.

**3.** Validate EVERY user input. Otherwise a failed input can set an error-bit on your input stream and additional attempts to read from a stream with an error-bit set can result in undefined behavior. You could do:

```
    if (!getline(cin,str1)) {   /* VALIDATE every input */
        cerr << "error: input failure - str1.\n";
        return 1;
    }
```

and

```
    if (cin.get (str, sizeof str))
        cout << str << endl;
```

(**note:** there are no further attempted reads after `cin.get (str, sizeof str)` so guarding your use of `str` is sufficient)

**4.** Always output a newline after your final line output to ensure your program is POSIX compliant. Otherwise on many OS's you will mess up the users prompt if writing to `stdout` or you will create a non-POSIX compliant output file if redirecting the output to a file, e.g.

```
my cat has none01:22 wizard:~/dev/src-cpp/tmp/debug>
```

Putting it altogether, you could do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   /* depending on your compiler */

#define MAXC 200    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

    char str[MAXC]; /* don't use 'magic-number', use a constant */
    string str1;

    cout << "enter a string: ";
    if (!getline(cin,str1)) {   /* VALIDATE every input */
        cerr << "error: input failure - str1.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    cout << str1 << endl;

    cout << "enter second string: ";
    // cin >> str;  /* not needed */
    if (cin.get (str, sizeof str))
        cout << str << endl;

}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cin.get_getline
enter a string: my dog has fleas
my dog has fleas
enter second string: my cat has none
my cat has none
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cout<<"enter second string:\t";
cin>>str;
cin.get(str,200);
```

here first you are trying to read the second word twice into same variable. comment one of them and try to print the content of str.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char str[200]; 
    string str1;
    cout<<"Enter a string:\t";
    getline(cin,str1);
    cout<<str1 <<endl;
    cout<<"enter second string:\t";
    // cin>>str;
    cin.get(str,200);
    cout<<str<<endl;

}
```